# jQuery .each() assign different actions to different buttons

Tags: jquery

As I said in my last post, I'm currently trying to do a Rock,Paper, Scissors game using jQuery, however, I encountered another problem. I want the computer to choose Rock, Paper or Scissors randomly. Therefore I used Math.random() to choose a random number between 0 and 1 and than I assigned the different ranges to a Rock, Paper or Scissors (which I saved in the variable "guess")
I then wanted to check if the chosen value corresponds to the value of the text in the buttons (.choice2). If it corresponds to it I wanted to change the background to red, if  not I want the button to disappear. For some reasons it just hides ALL of the buttons though, which I don't understand.

HTML for the buttons:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Computer's Choice:</h3>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="choice2 btn btn-submit">Rock</button>
            <button class="choice2 btn btn-submit">Paper</button>
            <button class="choice2 btn btn-submit">Scissors</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Player's Choice:</h3>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="choice1 btn btn-submit">Rock</button>
            <button class="choice1 btn btn-submit">Paper</button>
            <button class="choice1 btn btn-submit">Scissors</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.getVal = function () {
    var comp_choice = Math.random();

    if(comp_choice <= 0.33)
       var guess = "Rock"
    }
    else if ((comp_choice >0.33) && (comp_choice <= 0.66)) {
        var guess = "Paper"
    }

    else {
        var guess = "Scissors" 
    }

    $('.choice2').each(function () {

        if (guess == $('.choice2').text()) {

            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        }

        else {
            $('.choice2').not($(this)).hide();
        }
   });

};
```

Comment: should it not be `guess == $(this).text()`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n00zsaje/

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it: instead of $('.choice2').not($(this)).hide(); I used $(this).hide();

```
$.fn.getVal = function () {

    var comp_choice = Math.random();

    var guess = '';

    if(comp_choice <= 0.33) {
        guess = "Rock"
    }
    else if ((comp_choice >0.33) && (comp_choice <= 0.66)) {
        guess = "Paper"
    }

    else {
        guess = "Scissors" 
    }

    $('.choice2').each(function () {

        if (guess == $(this).text()) {

            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        }

        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: I will once I'm able to